# Does $\| \widehat{f} \|_{L^\infty} \le C \|f\|_{L^{1,2}}$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\widehat{f}$ be a Fourier transform of $f$.
It is well-known that $\|\widehat{f}\|_{L^\infty} \le C \|f\|_{L^1}$.
However, this is a very rough estimate, and $\widehat{f}$ has many good properties when $f \in L^1$.

So I wonder if the following estimate holds or not:
$$
\|\widehat{f}\|_{L^\infty} \le C \|f\|_{L^{1,2}},
$$
where $L^{p,q}$ is a standard notation for Lorentz spaces.

Comment: If $f\ge 0,$ then $\widehat{f}(0)=\|f\|_{L^1}.$ Hence you cannot expect that your inequality holds.